# Select the first occurence of a child element with a class

Tags: css

Need to select the first `td` that is not hidden from this table. That is the first `td` having the class `ts-wrap`

```
<table>
    <tr class="ts-row">
        <td style="display:none;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="display:none;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2">Select Me</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ts-row">
        <td style="display:none;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="display:none;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2">Select Me too</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" class="ts-wrap" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tried `.ts-row td.ts-wrap:first-child` and `.ts-row td.ts-wrap:first-of-type` in both CSS and jQuery; both of them are not for this scenario

`.ts-row td.ts-wrap:first` is working for jQuery but not a valid CSS selector.

How to achieve this in CSS?

Comment: .ts-row .ts-wrap:first-child does not work

Comment: [`.ts-row:first-of-type .ts-wrap{color:red}`](https://jsfiddle.net/d1kva5gm/)